# How to check if a folder exists in a git tag

Tags: git, tags

I need to push various versions of code to git during release and rollback to previous version in case of issues.

We are using tags for release.

For rollback, I would like to check if the code folder exists in previous tag.

I am aware that I can use git-cat file but that does not help in my case as the code will already be in branch before deployment in our process.

Is there a way to check if a folder exists in a git tag?
I would then like to use the return value for mt script.

Comment: git tags can point to any git object, blobs, trees, commits, etc., so I don't think there's a reliable way to do this. if the tag refs a commit or tree, you could do this, but again, not reliable. you should be able to roll back to the last reliable release without this kind of inspection

Comment: instead of looking for a specific git command, and if the tag is tree-ish, why don't you just check it out and stat the directory??

Answer (score 4):

There's a relatively direct and simple answer to a question that you *didn't* ask, which is: just run `git cat-file -t commit-specifier:path`.  If it says that this exists and is a *tree* object, the commit you specified contains files that would go into a folder with that name.  If it says that this is some other kind of object, the commit you specified does not contain such files: it has this object instead.  If this fails entirely, the commit you specified does not contain any object with that name.  Hence:

```
objid="${tagname}:${path}"
objtype=$(git cat-file -t $objid 2>/dev/null) || objtype=none
case $objtype in
none) echo no such folder would be created;;
blob) echo the specified path holds a file rather than a folder;;
tree) echo a folder would be created and contain some files;;
commit) echo the specified path refers to a submodule;;
*) echo something went terribly wrong;;
esac
```

You can turn these various `echo`s into whatever exit status you like.  This is probably the answer you want.

#### Answering what you asked, rather than what I think you meant to ask

The question you actually asked, though, was:

> Is there a way to check if a folder exists in a git tag?

A *tag* is just a name—typically along the lines of `v2.1` or similar—that refers to some Git object.  That Git object is usually an *annotated tag object* or a *commit*.  If the tag name refers directly to a commit, Git calls this a *lightweight tag*.  If the tag name refers to an annotated tag object, Git calls this an *annotated tag*.  The annotated tag object then refers to another object.

In some cases, an annotated tag object's target object is another annotated tag.  If so, Git can read this *second* tag object, which refers to another object.  That object can be another annotated tag object: if so, Git keeps reading and following, until eventually some annotated tag object refers to something other than an annotated tag object.  In other words, while an annotated tag object can "keep flying" by pointing to another one, eventually all such chains "fall to the ground", as it were.  Git calls this process, following tag objects until Git reaches a non-tag-object, *peeling the tag*.  Peeling a tag eventually leads to one of the remaining possible object types: *commit*, *tree*, or *blob*.

So, technically, no tag ever stores *any* file *or* folder.  It just names a *commit*.  And, unfortunately, no *commit* stores a folder either.  Fortunately, this isn't important!

#### Why I think you meant to ask something else

The technical reason that Git does not store folders is that it makes new commits from its *index* and the index cannot store folder names.<sup>1</sup>  It does, however, take the index's *files'* names, which can be quite long and can contain forward slashes (e.g., `dir/sub/file.ext`), and break them up into *component parts*.  So when the *index* holds a file named `dir/sub/file.ext`, Git will create a tree object named `dir`, referring to a tree object named `sub`, referring to a blob object named `file.ext`.  We'll see how this works in a moment.

Getting back to commits, a commit object holds a commit.  A commit represents a full and complete snapshot of your source.  Internally, it does so by pointing to (holding the hash ID of) a *tree* object.  Here, for instance, is an actual commit in the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
51ebf55b9309824346a6589c9f3b130c6f371b8f
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 7db7271b4def298424e57b0a04129f6a929955d0
parent f97741f6e9c46a75b4322760d77322e53c4322d7
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1581974501 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1581974539 -0800

The sixth batch for 2.26

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

Note the first line, `tree 7db7271b4def298424e57b0a04129f6a929955d0`.  This is the snapshot saved in commit `51ebf55b9309824346a6589c9f3b130c6f371b8f`.

A tree object holds an array of three-tuples: <component-name, mode, hash-ID>.  The component name is a portion of a path name.  The mode is one of a small set of allowed octal numbers, representing sub-trees, commit objects (gitlinks), or blob objects (file and symbolic link contents).  If the mode is that of a tree or blob object, the hash ID in the entry *must* be that of a Git object holding a tree or blob object respectively.

Here is part of what is in `tree` object `7db7271b4def298424e57b0a04129f6a929955d0`:

```
$ git cat-file -p 7db7271b4def298424e57b0a04129f6a929955d0
[snip]
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
040000 tree d12f433f975c365f2516022fd6ba597548a12a55    Documentation
100755 blob 616d5a6404e4f1a6550b2aca89488889dbe6d34f    GIT-VERSION-GEN
100644 blob 22c364f34f573c615d968a85374ba2c429b7fabd    INSTALL
100644 blob d38b1b92bdb2893eb4505667375563f2d6d4086b    LGPL-2.1
[snip]
```

Note how ordinary files such as `COPYING` and `GIT-VERSION-GEN` are stored as *blob* object references in this top-level tree.  However, `Documentation` is not the name of any file.  When this commit gets extracted, some files will have names that *start with* `Documentation/`.  Here's a bit of what is in tree `d12f433f975c365f2516022fd6ba597548a12a55`:

```
$ git cat-file -p d12f433f975c365f2516022fd6ba597548a12a55
[snip]
100644 blob aa828dfdc44a856c8bdd8b0826defeb398113bcc    MyFirstObjectWalk.txt
040000 tree 467d9eb934bfbb8ff63f5d239b2d4c975ab8e9b9    RelNotes
100644 blob 4515cab5193ddf354a461aafb1b68dcc1ef2932e    SubmittingPatches
[snip]
```

This shows us that when this commit is extracted, so that you have some files to work with, one of those files will be named `Documentation/MyFirstObjectWalk.txt` and one will be named `Documentation/SubmittingPatches`.  Since there's also a sub-tree named `RelNotes`, there must be files whose names begin with `Documentation/RelNotes/`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The closest the index comes to this is that it *can* store *gitlink* names.  Gitlinks have mode `160000`, which is the mode you get by OR-ing together the symlink mode `120000` with the tree mode `040000`.  It's kind of a shame that you cannot get a mode `040000` index entry, as that *would* let Git store empty folders.

---

#### What this all means

If we find a *commit object hash ID*, e.g., by `git rev-parse v2.1` if there is a tag named `v2.1`, we can inspect the commit object.  It will have a `tree` entry.

We can then inspect that *tree* object.  If it has a sub-tree, as the one above has `Documentation`, then we can *assume* that there must be files in that commit whose name *begins with* `Documentation/`.  In order to *extract* such a commit, Git would have to *create* a folder named `Documentation`.

The commit *does not contain this folder*.<sup>2</sup>  But *extracting* the commit *does produce* such a folder in your work-tree.  This is probably what you care about: that *extracting* the commit (with `git checkout`), or moving to it (with `git reset --hard`), for instance, would create, or perhaps remove,<sup>3</sup> such a folder in your work-tree.

Testing for the presence of this tree object within any given commit *this* way, by checking each level one step at a time, is painful.  But the `git rev-parse` command, which can turn *any* valid name into a Git object hash ID, makes this easy.  So, while you can run `git rev-parse hash` to see if *`hash`* is a valid Git object ID, you can also run `git rev-parse hash:path` to see if *`hash`* can be turned into a *commit* object and then have a path name parsed from it.  That path name will automatically refer to some Git object; `git rev-parse` will produce its hash ID.

We don't really want the *hash ID* though.  That just tells us that some object exists, without telling us what *type* the object has.  To find the object's *type* we need `git cat-file -t`.  This takes the name or ID of any object and tells us the type—or produces an error if the ID is not valid:

```
$ git cat-file -t d12f433f975c365f2516022fd6ba597548a12a55
tree
$ git cat-file -t 616d5a6404e4f1a6550b2aca89488889dbe6d34f
blob
$ git cat-file -t a123456
fatal: Not a valid object name a123456
```

If we supply an annotated tag object's tag name we get:

```
$ git cat-file -t v2.23.0
tag
```

Telling Git to *peel* the tag, using `^{}`, we find the target object:

```
$ git cat-file -t v2.23.0^{}
commit
```

and telling Git to look inside this commit for a path name, we get:

```
$ git cat-file -t v2.23.0:Documentation
tree
```

which is more informative than:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.23.0:Documentation
b55461e880f78ae8253c8be287476cbbddd44957
```

so this is the way to go.

---

<sup>2</sup>If you call a *tree object* a "folder", you could claim that the commit does contain a folder—but that's not quite how Git actually works.  The sub-tree object can only exist in the commit if there are *files* within it.  It's sometimes annoying that this is the case, but this is the case.

<sup>3</sup>When a `git checkout` moves from a cleanly-checked-out commit that contains, e.g., `sub/one` and `sub/two` to a commit that has *no* files that the OS requires be placed in a folder named `sub/`, Git will of course delete those two files from the work-tree.  They *are* in the index and work-tree right now, but they're *not* in the target commit, so they must go away.  Having deleted both files, Git will *delete the empty `sub/` folder* from the work-tree as well.  If the `sub/` folder *isn't* empty, due to the presence of untracked files, Git will *not* delete it.  That's now all this works: Git *creates folders* on the OS's demand that they exist in order for files to go into them.  Git *removes* them when it empties them, but not if it doesn't empty them.  Otherwise, Git just doesn't touch them at all.